# Fancybox: What is the best way to trigger fancybox iframe from another function

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I would like to launch fancybox from another function. I need this trigger after some ajax function get success.

**Code Base**

```
$.post('principals/search_post/'+value, function(data) {

   **// I need to call fancybox here**

});
```

**EDIT**

I have a url like http://example.com/somepage. I need to open this in an iframe with fancybox after that ajax function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean

```
$.post('principals/search_post/'+value, function(data) {
    $("a.images").fancybox();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can open fancybox manually:

```
$.fancybox.open({
    href: 'your_url',
    type: 'iframe'
});
```